# C# function that execute same code with diffrent variables in the same code

Tags: c#, function, duplicates

I have algorithm that store decimal number with int variables. And I have to sum two decimal numbers. So I am wondering Can i avoid duplicating converting code, and use function with same converting code with only diffrent storage variables.

```
namespace structSimple
{
    class Program
    {

        struct decimalanBroj
        {
            public int cijeliDio;
            public int decimalanDio;
            public int potencija;
        };

        static decimalanBroj baze()
        {
            String number = "100";
            int fromBase = 16;
            int toBase = 10;

            String result = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(number, fromBase), toBase);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            decimalanBroj d = new decimalanBroj();
            decimalanBroj e = new decimalanBroj();


            Console.WriteLine("Unesite cijeli dio broj: ");
            d.cijeliDio = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Unesite decimalna dio broj: ");
            d.decimalanDio = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            d.potencija = d.decimalanDio.ToString().Length;
            Console.WriteLine( d.cijeliDio + (d.decimalanDio * (Math.Pow(10, -d.potencija))));


            Console.WriteLine("Unesite cijeli dio broj2: ");
            e.cijeliDio = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Unesite decimalna dio broj2: ");
            e.decimalanDio = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            e.potencija = e.decimalanDio.ToString().Length;


            Console.WriteLine("Zbroj dva broja: {0}",
                (d.cijeliDio + (d.decimalanDio * (Math.Pow(10, -d.potencija)))) + 
                (e.cijeliDio + (e.decimalanDio * (Math.Pow(10, -e.potencija ) ))));




        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile: `static decimalanBroj baze()` needs to return a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your struct to a class with a method doing your calculation:

```
public class decimalanBroj
{
    public int cijeliDio;
    public int decimalanDio;
    public int potencija;

    public int Calculate()
    {
        return cijeliDio + (decimalanDio * (Math.Pow(10, -potencija));
    }   
};
```

Now you can do your calulation without copying the code all the time:

```
decimalanBroj d = new decimalanBroj();   
...
d.Calculate();
```

Comment: If I were you, I'd show him how to assign the result of `d.Calculate();` to a variable. He's asking how to reuse a function for different variable inputs -- meaning his real problem is that he doesn't know what a function parameter is. There's no way he knows that he can return a value from his own function and assign it to something.

Answer (score 0):

Add Method to do it for you:

```
static decimalanBroj GetDecimalanBroj()
    { 
    var d = new decimalanBroj();
        Console.WriteLine("Unesite cijeli dio broj: ");
        d.cijeliDio = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Unesite decimalna dio broj: ");
        d.decimalanDio = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        d.potencija = d.decimalanDio.ToString().Length;
        Console.WriteLine(d.cijeliDio + (d.decimalanDio * (Math.Pow(10, -d.potencija))));
        return d;

    }
```

Then call the method in the Main() like this:

```
        decimalanBroj d = GetDecimalanBroj();
        decimalanBroj e = GetDecimalanBroj();
```